# How to connect my android java app with a SQL database?

Tags: java, android, sql

I was wondering what is the best way to connect my android app to a SQL database? I've seen many ways to do it such as using a JDBC connector, writing PHP scripts and so on..so I wanted to know what is your recommendation on how to do it?

Comment: JDBC is for java,if you're using android then yes JDBC, and on your frontend if its PHP you call your backend to do some stuff to the data.

Answer (score 0):

using php scripts is better option. you can use php frameworks such as codeignitor and laravel etc.. many apps in market are using php api's to connect with online sql database

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use **API** while connecting the android app with any database.
You can build an API using **PHP scripts, node.js** etc. These languages provide a very easy interface to connect to different databases.

There are many libraries which provide an easy interface let android interact with an API, I prefer [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Another advantage of using an API is that you can connect to another database by changing very few lines of code in API and even without changing anything in app code.